# FEM with no homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations, finite-element-method

I am mechanical engineer and I have been using the FEM regularly for several years. However, I feel that I have never really understand the basis of the principle. I am using the heat equation to try to understand how the method is developed.

$$
\Delta{T} = q \\
T(\partial \Omega) = g
$$

Firsts of all, I need to convert this PDE to the weak form, for which I multiply both sides by a test function $v$ and integrate. So first question, what are the conditions that $v$ must have? In some places I read "any test function", but in other places I read "compatible test functions".

$$
\int_\Omega {v\Delta Td\Omega} = \int_\Omega {vg d\Omega} \\
\int_\Omega v\Delta Td\Omega = -\int_\Omega {\nabla{v} \nabla{T}} d\Omega + \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\nabla T \cdot n) \partial \Omega = \int_\Omega vg d\Omega
$$

We can chose $T = \sum_i^N  T_i \cdot \phi_i$ and I chose j test functions $v_j = \psi_j$ to get j equations

$$
\sum_i^N T_i \int_\Omega {\nabla{\psi_j} \nabla{\phi_i}} d\Omega  = \sum_i^N T_i \int_{\partial \Omega} \psi_j (\nabla \phi_i \cdot n) \partial \Omega - \int_\Omega \psi_j g d\Omega
$$

In nearly all the articles I have read, they now assume homogeneous boundary conditions, and they chose shape functions $\phi_i = \psi_j$ vanishing at the boundary. With that selection, the boundary integral dissappears, and the boundary condition is enforced by construction, as the field $T$ has a value of 0 by construction on the boundary.

However, what happens when we have non-homogeneous boundary conditions? I guess we can select different shape functions for the field interpolation and the test functions ($\phi_i \neq \psi_j$), with $\psi_j$ vanishing at the boundary. That way, the boundary integral dissapears, but I still get equations for the values $T_i$ at the boundary, which I can impose while solving the system of equations.

However, this approach allows me to have "nodal" boundary conditions, but I am not sure how to proceed with "distributed" boundary conditions. How I could treat a region in my domain with a specified T value? Do I need to do the integral on the boundary?

Comment: I find the question "what are the conditions that $v$ must have?" very on point but also quite hard to answer since it inevitably leads to many technical details. This is why you usually find the vague descriptions like "compatible test function". Then it depends how technical do you want the answer to be?

Comment: You can go technical if its needed. But I am more interested in the BC stuff. Does it make sense selecting different shape functions, one for discarding the boundary integration and one for making the T_i appear in my system of equations?

Comment: Regarding the BC stuff, you kind of select different shape functions, make the boundary $T_i$'s appear and impose their values from $g$. My answer is a bit clunky, I think we are using some terms in slightly different meanings.

Comment: Yeah, I think we are doing the same, although I feel like the method you described is better supported by theory. In my method I have to build the problem and the modify A to impose the BC, while in your method everything naturally arises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial answer without going into too much details, assuming that you are content with the choice of test functions $v$ that are zero on the boundary. We will keep the choice $\phi_i = \psi_j$. The trick to deal with boundary condition is to split $T$ to two parts
$$
T = T_0 + T_g
$$
such that $T_0(\partial\Omega) = 0$ and $T_g(\partial\Omega) = g$ and find the solution for. We plug this into the so called weak formulation
$$
\int_\Omega {\nabla{v} \nabla{T}} d\Omega = -\int_\Omega vg d\Omega + \int_{\partial \Omega} v (\nabla T \cdot n) \partial \Omega
$$
and get
$$
\int_\Omega {\nabla{v} \nabla{T_0}} d\Omega = -\int_\Omega vg d\Omega + \underbrace{\int_{\partial \Omega} v (\nabla T \cdot n) \partial \Omega}_{=0} - \int_\Omega {\nabla{v} \nabla{T_g}} d\Omega .
$$
The second term is zero thanks to the choice of $v$ vanishing at the boundary. We are now almost at the same position as in the case of homogeneous boundary, only this time not for $T$ but for $T_0$.

The extra term with $T_g$ is a bit problematic in the sense that we do not know exactly $T_g$ looks like. The key observation is that it actually does not matter how it looks like as long as it satisfies $T_g(\partial\Omega) = g$. The convenient choice for implementation is
$$
T_g := \sum_i \tilde g_i \phi_i^{boundary}
$$
where $\phi_i^{boundary}$ are the basis functions that have nonzero values on boundary and $\tilde g_i$ are computed from $g(x)$ in a way that satisfies $T_g(\partial\Omega) = g$, up to some discretization error.

This might be a bit clearer if you write it down in terms of vectors and matrices you get after discretization. You effectively get a problem
$$
A x = b
$$
where $A$ is the stiffness matrix, $b$ is the volume source term and $x$ the unknown vector. We know that $x$ should have some part with prescribed values that come from the boundary condition, so we split $x$ in to two parts
$$
x = x_0 + x_g
$$
where $x_g$ comes from degrees of freedom on boundary and we know its values from the boundary condition and $x_0$ is the rest. We just plug in the split, get
$$
Ax_0 = b - Ax_g
$$
and solve for $x_0$.

If a region in your domain would have some prescribed values, you could use the same approach of splitting $T = T_0 + T_p$ where $T_p$ is the part with prescribed values and $T_0$ is the rest.

Comment: I think I understood it perfectly. So the boundary integral can still be removed, but now I am approximating the T field not only by the T_o, computed using the shape function, but only using the T_g, computed using the same shape functions, but aevaluated the boundary. I just impose the value of the BC at the nodes, and when integrating both sides, I get the contribution of the T_g (so of the BC) to the whole domain.

Comment: Yes, I think it should be as you describe. It might get a little bit messier in the actual computation if you use more complicated shape function e. g. for wave equation. There are also alternative approaches to the one described here, using [penalisation](https://mooseframework.inl.gov/source/bcs/PenaltyDirichletBC.html) which might be convenient for some applications.